# How extract an element from a Set collection using Spring Expression Language for caching purposes

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a class like this

```
public class RegionShopMap {

private Integer regionId;
private String shopId;
}
```

and DAO method which saves batch of these objects using a Set collection.
Method signature:

```
void saveRegionShops(Set<RegionShopMap> regionShopMapSet);
```

My problem is that i am trying to do a cache evict using as key the regionId from a RegionShopMap object from the Set.The regionId is the same for all the objects in the Set.
I don't know how to use Spring Expression Language to extract the regionId.
I have tried something like this:

```
@CacheEvict(value = "Shop.byRegionId", key ="#regionShopMapSet[0].regionId")
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated or maybe another kind of solution.

Thank you very much

Comment: If the regionId is same for all the objects then why provide a `key` attribute in annotation? Just providing the cache name in `value` should be enough to clear the entire cache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to extract the value of regionId using EL, then what you wrote works pretty fine.

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
static class RegionShopMap {
    private Integer regionId;
    private String shopId;
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    ExpressionParser parser = new SpelExpressionParser();
    StandardEvaluationContext context = new StandardEvaluationContext();
    Set<RegionShopMap> regionShopMapSet = new HashSet<>();
    regionShopMapSet.add(new RegionShopMap(1, "2"));
    regionShopMapSet.add(new RegionShopMap(3, "4"));

    context.setVariable("regionShopMapSet", regionShopMapSet);
    Expression exp = parser.parseExpression("#regionShopMapSet[1].regionId");
    System.out.println(exp.getValue(context));
    return;
}
```

However as you mentioned, the value of `regionId` is going to be the same for all objects.
In which case you should try using `CacheEvict` without any Key.

Comment: Thank for your help.The thing is the regionId will be the same at the Set level but i will have different sets ,each with its own regionId so I think CacheEvict by key works better for me.I have another question though.In order to run the code you wrote do i have to do anything else besides putting it in the main method? Thank you again

Comment: @RaduD Just main method with Spring dependency in maven should do. I found this approach the best to test SpringEL. I've edited the answer with full code of how I tested it.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: @RaduD If your question was answered, can you close out the question by accepting the answer?